# How can I repair uneven tile grout?

Tags: flooring

I had ceramic installed in my kitchen about a year ago. In 75% of the kitchen the grout is not level with the rest do I have to remove all the grout and start over or can it be floated to fill in the low places

Answer (score 3):

All the existing grout won't need to be completely removed but you'll need to use a grout removal tool to cut into the existing grout so that your new grout has a little more to grab on to.

Comment: I wonder if a polymer grout would allow direct placement without the need to cut in any?

Comment: It may... My worry is of bonding of the new grout to old sealed grout. You'll either end up with a dry joint where the new grout will eventually fall out or the new grout can be wiped "off" during normal cleaning...